# Set of intersections a set of functions is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

I have a closed set $A$ of continuous functions. That is, $A$ is a closed set in  $C([0,1] \rightarrow R^n)$.
I also have a compact set $B$ of functions in $C([0,1] \rightarrow R^n)$.

I want to show that the set $$\{y \in R^n : y = f(t) = g(t')\; \text{ for some } f \in A, \;g \in B,\; t,t' \in [0,1]   \}$$ of the intersections of the functions in $A$ and $B$ is measurable.

My problem is, I know that the set of intersections of a couple of functions is closed, but here I have an infinite amount of functions in both sets.

Maybe the fact that the set $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact is not necessary, and a weaker version is enough.

Thank you for any help.